Need Help In Finding neighboring elements in APS Viewer
enter image description here
We're encountering difficulty locating adjacent elements to a selected object in the APS Viewer. For instance, if we choose a beam in a Revit file, we aim to identify neighboring objects such as walls, columns, or additional beams within the Revit file.
we are expecting solution to find neighboring element properties

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562162/get-elements-next-to-a-given-element-in-the-viewer
There's no straight forward solution. Sorry about that.
